# BeautifulSoup get text from an element containing substring

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scrapping a webpage that uploads different documents and I want to retrieve some information from this documents. At first I hard coded the scrapper to search the information on a certain xpath, but now I see that this might change depending on the document. Is there any way to get the text from an element that contains a substring?

Here's an example:

I want to get the company name, the HTML were it appears follows this:

```
<div id="fullDocument">
   <div class="tab">
      <div id="docHeader">...</div>
      <ul id="docToc">...</ul>
      <div class="stdoc">...</div>
      <div id="DocumentBody">
         <div class="stdoc">...</div>
         <div class="stdoc">...</div>
         <div class="stdoc">...</div>
         <div class="stdoc">...</div>
         <div class="grseq">
            <p class="tigrseq">...</p>
            <div class="mlioccur">
               <span class="nomark"></span>
               <span class="timark"></span>
               <div class="txtmark">
                  "Official name: Company Name"
                  <br>
                  "Identification: xxxxxx"
                  <br>
                  "Postal code: 00000"
                  <br>
                  "City: city"
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

For this example, I hardcoded into my script the following code:

```
from lxml import etree

class LTED:
   def __init__(self, url, soup):
      if(not soup)
         soup = get_soup_from_url(url, "html.parser")
         dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

      self.organization = self.get_organization(dom)

   def get_organization(self, dom):
      item = dom.xpath("/div[@id='fullDocument']/div/div[3]/div[5]/div/div")[0].text
      return item.split(": ")[1]
```

This actually works for the example, but as I mentioned the problem is that the xpath might change depending on the document, for example, instead of `"/div[@id='fullDocument']/div/div[3]/div[5]/div/div"` might change to `"/div[@id='fullDocument']/div/div[3]/div[6]/div/div"` or something similar.

Trying to solve this I searched on the Internet and found this, but didn't work for me:

```
item = soup.find_all("div", string="Official name:")
```

I expected this to return a list with all elements containing the substring `"Official name:"` but it gave me an empty list `[]`.

Is there any way to get the element containing the substring so independently of the xpath I can always get the Company Name and any other information I might need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected this to return a list with all elements containing the substring "Official name:" but it gave me an empty list [].

That is because it needs an exact match, but you could use `re.compile`:

```
import re
soup.find_all(text = re.compile('Official name:'))
```

---

However, why not using an alternative approach (selecting by class) that will give you a structured output?

For a single one:

```
dict(i.strip('"').split(': ') for i in soup.select_one('#DocumentBody div.txtmark').stripped_strings)

### leads to
{'Official name': 'Company Name',
  'Identification': 'xxxxxx',
  'Postal code': '00000',
  'City': 'city'}
```

or for multiple in your document:

```
[dict(i.strip('"').split(': ') for i in list(e.stripped_strings)) for e in soup.select('div.txtmark')]


### leads to
[{'Official name': 'Company Name',
  'Identification': 'xxxxxx',
  'Postal code': '00000',
  'City': 'city'},
 {'Official name': 'Company Name B',
  'Identification': 'xxxxxx',
  'Postal code': '00000',
  'City': 'city'}]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div id="fullDocument">
   <div class="tab">
      <div id="docHeader">...</div>
      <ul id="docToc">...</ul>
      <div class="stdoc">...</div>
      <div id="DocumentBody">
         <div class="stdoc">...</div>
         <div class="stdoc">...</div>
         <div class="stdoc">...</div>
         <div class="stdoc">...</div>
         <div class="grseq">
            <p class="tigrseq">...</p>
            <div class="mlioccur">
               <span class="nomark"></span>
               <span class="timark"></span>
               <div class="txtmark">
                  "Official name: Company Name"
                  <br>
                  "Identification: xxxxxx"
                  <br>
                  "Postal code: 00000"
                  <br>
                  "City: city"
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

dict(i.strip('"').split(': ') for i in soup.select_one('#DocumentBody div.txtmark').stripped_strings)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I didn't consider the second option you gave because the original html is way bigger than the one I gave for the example and the class `txtmak` appears plenty of times. Will give it a try to it and if it doesn't return a lot of unnecessary information will keep it. If it's not viable will try with the first option. Thanks!

Comment: Just updated with a similar problem but the html is different, would be great if you could check that

Comment: To keep context of original question and answer, this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus. If you like to reference the new one in the comments, we will have a look. Would be great, thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i'm pretty new and didn't know, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430358/beautifulsoup-get-text-from-tag-searching-by-title)'s the new question