# BeautifulSoup get text from tag searching by Title

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scrapping a webpage with python that provides different documents and I want to retrieve some information from them. The document gives the information in two ways, there's this one where it gives it like this: `Company name: Company name` which is solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74401988/beautifulsoup-get-text-from-an-element-containing-substring) question, and another one that goes like `Title:` and then all the text on a separate block of text, here's an example of this second html starting at div with class DocumentBody:

```
<div class="DocumentBody">
   <div class="stdoc">...</div>
   <div class="stdoc">...</div>
   <div class="stdoc">...</div>
   <div class="grseq">...</div>
   <div class="grseq">
      <p class="tigrseq">...</p>
      <div class="mlioccur">...</div>
      <div class="mlioccur">
         <span class="nomark">...</span>
         <span class="timark">Denomination:</span>
         <div class="txtmark">
            <p class="p"> </p>
            <p>Information about denomination</p>
            <p></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

At first I tried hardcoding the xpath to the text, but the problem is that the html from the documents might change, they are not always the same.

This is an example of what I made to get the denomination:

```
from lxml import etree

class LTED:
   def __init__(self, url, soup):
      if(not soup)
         soup = get_soup_from_url(url, "html.parser")
         dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

      # case document it's updated and not a new one
      self.corrigenda = bool(soup.body.findAll(text="Corrigenda"))

      self.denomination = self.get_denomination(dom)

   def get_denomination(self, dom):
      if self.corrigenda:
         item = dom.xpath("//div[@class='DocumentBody']/div[7]/div[2]/div/p[2]")[0].text
      else:
         item = dom.xpath("//div[@class='DocumentBody']/div[6]/div[2]/div/p[2]")[0].text
      return item
```

As the xpath is hardcoded, this works the majority of the time, but in some cases it gets another text because the html has changed.

How should I retrieve the text in this case? Is there any way to get `Information about denomination` searching by `Denomination`?

In case you want to check the webpage, here's a [link](https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:628602-2022:TEXT:ES:HTML&src=0) to an example I'm trying to scrape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link do not contain such `Denomination` but you can adapt and proceed like:

```
for e in soup.select('span:-soup-contains("Title:") + div'):
    print(e.get_text(strip=True))
```

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:628602-2022:TEXT:EN:HTML&tabId=0',
                                  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text)

for e in soup.select('div.txtmark:-soup-contains("Official name:")'):
    print(e.next.split(':')[-1].strip())

for e in soup.select('span:-soup-contains("Title:") + div'):
    print(e.get_text(strip=True))
```

##### Output

```
KfW Bankengruppe
Vergabekammer Bund
Management of the PtX-Fund by the Power-to-X D&G GmbH (in formation)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks again! link does not contain `Denomination` because the page is in Spanish and I translated it for the question, in the link appears as `Denominación`. Will also have in count the new syntax. Thanks again for all your help!